# Jetty + rest + cdi with maven

Tags: rest, jetty, cdi

Simple question; can anyone point me to a pom.xml which has Jetty 10 or 11 working with REST and CDI?

All my googling only finds me examples with old jetty versions.

Comment: You have to narrow it down a bit.  Jetty standalone? Jetty home/base? Jetty embedded? What REST implementation? (jakarta based, or other?), which CDI impl (weld? owb? other?)  What have you tried? - this kind of question is typically not a great one for stackoverflow as it has too many possible answers.

Comment: Jetty embedded then whatever REST/CDI works best. I don't mind which, just whichever is the least fuss to setup! I had tried using jersey/WELD but started getting lots of HK2 related errors (plenty of posts on SO with same sort of thing). I realise this isn't a yes/no answer, was just hoping for any that works!

Comment: If this is only about minimal hassle and not a hard requirement to use jetty, simply use undertow/RESTEasy/Weld. Example setup here: https://wiki.jarylchng.com/en/programming/java/minimal-undertow-resteasy-and-weld-cdi-setup

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I eventually used...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.fu.bar/groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>server</name>
    <description>server</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <jetty.version>11.0.9</jetty.version>
        <jersey.version>3.0.5</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```